# Make a div that has literally no background and triggers events below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to come up with a hack for HighCharts. I tried to render a SVG rectangle thats draggable with jQuery UI on top of HighChart but the problem is that Firefox, Chrome, and IE are all a little off when dragging it.

So, my last attempt is to make a div on top of the chart with another div inside that is used as the draggable element I was trying to create with SVG. This is far more reliable in all the browsers and easier to style, but the problem is that now I can't directly interact with the chart anymore. I tried background:transparent and background:none but still nothing.

Any ideas or hacks?

Comment: It seems strange to me that the SVG method was "off". Dragging a rect is pretty basic, but you need to make sure you're transforming the coordinate system correctly. I'm also not sure what jQuery UI would do for you in this case. Can you link to an example that illustrates where this broke down?

Comment: It worked in IE and Chrome, just not FF. I was simply doing: `e.target.setAttribute('x', ui.position.left);` Here's an example of the old, broken-ish chart: http://jsbin.com/aginuf . The new chart is working fine now that I redid it with divs: http://jsbin.com/ucebar

Comment: Also, if you notice in the redid div one i can't go back to the first point after moving it once. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two pages in Firefox 6 beta, except that the plot is broken on the div page. I'm also not seeing the behaviour you mentioned in your second comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the opacity 0 and see if it works.

Comment: Doesn't look like and it also makes all the children 0 so the slider disappears.